# Tomcat server on Amazon EC2 (windows) instance is not responding remotely

Tags: windows, web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have created a dynamic web service application using Eclipse Juno on Amazon EC2 (Windows) instance and deployed it on a local server. It's working fine using `localhost:8080/<pageAddress>` but when I try to hit the same URL with `<EC2-Public DNS>:8080/<pageAddress>`, it does not respond.

I just hit the Public DNS url and it shows me IIS image showing IIS is working fine. I have disabled Windows firewall on EC2 instance. I have also added inbound rule for `port 8080 (HTTP*)` for security group linked with my EC2 instance but still it's not responding as if server is down.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually got it working soon after posting the question.

I didn't do anything special but I got it working by somehow. My best assumption is that when I added a inbound rule for port-8080, it took some time to get into effect or may be, same might be the case for disabling firewall for Windows on EC2-instance. Anyway, it's working fine now.

Comment: It is a firewall issue. Turn off the firewall for the public network.

Answer (score 0):

disable the firewall and try it that should work ..

how to disable firewall in windows :-
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000551.htm